# check if sorted using recursion in python

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

I am trying to check if a list is sorted using recursion in python. Returns true if sorted, False if not sorted.

```
def isSorted(L):
    if len(L) < 2:
       return True
```

Now, I am not sure what I should be doing next.Please help!

Comment: You should write a unit test for this :) And then assert that a list of x items is in the correct order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check first two items.

If they are ordered, check next items using recursion:

```
def isSorted(L):
    if len(L) < 2:
        return True
    return L[0] <= L[1] and isSorted(L[1:])
```

**Side note** The function can be expression as a single expression as thefourtheye commented:

```
return len(L) < 2 or (L[0] <= L[1] and isSorted(L[1:]))
```

Comment: `return len(L) < 2 or (L[0] <= L[1] and isSorted(L[1:]))`?

Comment: +1. Could also avoid the list copy by taking in an extra argument for the index of the current element and increment this index in the recursive calls. Then define a wrapper to pass in the initial index set to 0. Base case will change to whether idx >= len(L) -1. But this captures the gist. Nice.

Comment: If you split the list in half at each step, the recursion depth will be log2(n)